# Cakephp date input issue

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I not 100% sure why this is happening, however, the issue I am having is that I have a very simple date input which works perfectly fine on my home server (generates a dropdown list of Years, Months, Days).  When I upload it to a remote server, an input field appears instead of a dropdown.

On the remote server I have tried both DATE and DATETIME fields in the database both producing the same results.

Here is the basic code:

```
echo $this->Form->input('event_date');
```

The version of cake is 1.3 (if that makes any difference).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove all the files in your *app/tmp* directory.

Cakephp will take the structure of tables to the cache.
Whenever you are making changes to database table structure, you have to clear the cache.